# Pedir mas de 10 datos sin usar tantas variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

Acabé de empezar con este mundo de Python y estoy haciendo un software personal de ejemplo.

Pero necesito pedir demasiados datos.

EJEMPLO:

```
dato1 = float(input("Dígame su peso en kg: "))
dato2 = float(input("Dígame su peso en kg: "))
dato5 = float(input("Dígame su peso en kg: "))
dato6 = float(input("Dígame su peso en kg: "))
dato7 = float(input("Dígame su peso en kg: "))
dato8 = float(input("Dígame su peso en kg: "))
dato9 = float(input("Dígame su peso en kg: "))
dato10 = float(input("Dígame su peso en kg: "))
```

Pero si el usuario necesita mas de 10 datos y solo tengo 10 variables ¿Qué puedo hacer? Lo que podría hacer fácilmente es llenarme de variables pero eso no quiero. Creo que existe otro medio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completando la respuesta de @PatricioMoracho y en relación a tu comentario en ella, si quieres que sea el usuario el que defina el número de datos a ingresar tienes dos opciones simples:

- Pedir al usuario previamente que ingrese el número de datos que desea ingresar y pasárselo a `range`:

  ```
  n = int(input("¿Cuántos datos dese ingresar? "))
  datos = [float(input("Dígame su peso en kg: ")) for _ in range(n)]
  ```
- Cambiar el `for` por un `while` que se rompa en base a una condición de salida que el usuario pueda proveer, por ejemplo ingresar datos hasta que uno de ellos tenga x valor o que se ingrese una cadena vacía:

  ```
  datos = []

  dato = input("Dígame su peso en kg: ")
  while dato:
      datos.append(float(dato))
      dato = input("Dígame su peso en kg: ")
  ```

En este caso el usuario puede ingresar datos indefinidamente (mientras exista memoria disponible para ser estrictos) hasta que ingrese una cadena vacía, momento en el que se rompe el ciclo.

Si deseas validar la entrada (por ejemplo impedir que se ingrese cualquier cosa que no sea un número positivo) y de paso evitar que el programa termine con una excepción si el casting a `float` no es posible, puedes valerte de una función accesoria:

```
def ingresar_peso():
    while True:
        try:
            cad = input("Dígame su peso en kg: ")
            if not cad:
                return None
            peso = float(cad)
            if peso < 0:
                raise ValueError()
            return peso
        except:
            print("Error, el peso debe ser un número positivo.")
            continue


datos = []

dato = ingresar_peso()
while dato:
    datos.append(float(dato))
    dato = ingresar_peso()
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

> ```
> Dígame su peso en kg: 56
> Dígame su peso en kg: dadda
> Error, el peso debe ser un número positivo.
> Dígame su peso en kg: 81
> Dígame su peso en kg: -55
> Error, el peso debe ser un número positivo.
> Dígame su peso en kg: 73
> Dígame su peso en kg: 
> >>> datos
> [56.0, 81.0, 73.0]
> ```

Answer (score 6):

En estos casos, cuando se trata de una serie de datos, puedes usar una estructura contenedora como puede ser una Lista:

```
dato = []
cantidad = 10

for i in range(10):
  dato.append(float(input("Dígame su peso en kg: ")))
```

Una lista es una colección de datos eventualmente de distinto tipo que pueden ser accedidos mediante un índice. Lo que hemos hecho en el ejemplo es pedir 10 valores de peso y guardarlos en el orden que los hemos ingresados en una variable tipo lista llamada `dato`. Para acceder a cada valor usamos el índice, por ejemplo:

```
print(dato[0]) # El primer elemento
print(dato[9]) # El último elemento
```

Algunas consideraciones importantes:

- Recuerda que el índice en toda lista comienza en la posición `0` por lo que décimo elemento corresponderá al índice `9`.
- La creación de una lista vacía puede hacerse usando los "corchetes", tal como en ele ejemplo: `dato = []`
- Como todo objeto, las listas tienen distintos métodos, uno de los que estamos usando es `append()` que permite agregar un elemento a la lista y lo coloca en la última posición

Para más información sobre listas:

- [Listas](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)
- [Mas sobre listas](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list#more-on-lists)

Comment: Y en dado caso que el usuario decida hasta un limite? digamos si solo tiene 5 datos?

Comment: @SAGCGC, no hay problema con la cantidad, las listas se redimensionan automáticamente, en ese caso, si es el usuario es el que decide la cantidad, se puede implementar un ciclo `while` y seguir usando `append()`para agregar elementos.